# how to determine which view has the Icarousel  stopped on?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, carousel

I am implementing iCarousel in my app but somehow can't figure out which view is in front when the carousel has stopped animating.Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When the iCarousel stops moving it calls the following delegate method:

```
- (void)carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation:(iCarousel *)carousel;
```

In that method, you can get the index of the frontmost view by calling

```
NSInteger frontmostViewIndex = carousel.currentItemIndex;
```

If you need the actual view itself, just pass that to the following method:

```
UIView *frontmostView = [carousel itemViewAtIndex:carousel.currentItemIndex];
```

Or use this property, which does the same thing internally:

```
UIView *frontmostView = carousel.currentItemView;
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thank You , So Much. I wasn't expecting Nick Lockwood himself coming to help me. If it is actually you than I must say that you have developed one hell of reusable thing. thanks again. :D

Comment: Well if I don't support my own stuff then who will? ;-)

Comment: Any idea for the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164687/carousel-index-are-not-in-order