# Carousel index are not in order

Tags: ios, objective-c, carousel, icarousel

I have the following plist and I want to show images on order on the carousel. When I debug the code, I see index are not order.

[image]

When I am debugging, first it shows `index = 0`, then next item is `index = 5`

```
(lldb) po [items objectAtIndex:index];
http://charcoaldesign.co.uk/AsyncImageView/Forest/IMG_0351.JPG
(lldb) po [items objectAtIndex:index];
http://charcoaldesign.co.uk/AsyncImageView/Forest/IMG_0358.JPG
```

**Here is the implementation:**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    //set up data
    //your carousel should always be driven by an array of
    //data of some kind - don't store data in your item views
    //or the recycling mechanism will destroy your data once
    //your item views move off-screen

    //get image URLs
    NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Images" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *imagePaths = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    //remote image URLs
    NSMutableArray *URLs = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *path in imagePaths)
    {
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
        if (URL)
        {
            [URLs addObject:URL];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"'%@' is not a valid URL", path);
        }
    }
    self.items = URLs;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    //it's a good idea to set these to nil here to avoid
    //sending messages to a deallocated viewcontroller
    carousel.delegate = nil;
    carousel.dataSource = nil;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //configure carousel
    carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    //free up memory by releasing subviews
    self.carousel = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark iCarousel methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //return the total number of items in the carousel
    return [items count];
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    //create new view if no view is available for recycling
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 200.0f)];
        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    }

    //cancel any previously loading images for this view
    [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingImagesForTarget:view];

    //set image URL. AsyncImageView class will then dynamically load the image
    ((AsyncImageView *)view).imageURL = [items objectAtIndex:index];

    return view;
}
```

if anyone wants to test, here is the [github](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel). then select and run **Dynamic Downloads** project

[image]

Comment: show ur previous code

Comment: it means your 1 to 4 items is missing

Comment: I have put the full code. It is adding each item with `foreach`

Comment: can you print this `URLs`  before here `self.items = URLs;`

Comment: or can you print your `self.items`

Comment: you are get the url is correctly, when u faced this

Comment: If you want to test, I have just added github link.

Comment: sure, its better

Comment: you are used dynamic download option in iCarosel, so , those are taken the  URL in random order, for e.g, `IMG_0351.JPG`,`IMG_0358.JPG`,`IMG_0352`,`IMG_0361`

Comment: How could I put them in order? All I need is to get index number in order.

Comment: @hotspring It's not clear what you mean by "get the index in number in order". The images should be displayed in the correct order in the carousel, but the order in which the `carousel:viewForItemAtIndex:` method is called isn't guaranteed, and shouldn't matter.